# Iterate through each element in a particular column of a dynamic table using cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a dynamic table displayed based on a value selected from a radio button in my project. The radio button field `"Doctor Name"` field has different choices like `"Frank", "Michael", "Josh", "Jessica"`. When I select the `"Frank"` value, it displays a dynamic table with the list of appointments for `"Frank"`, The first column in the table is `"Doctor Name"`. When I select `"Frank"` from the radio button, I have to validate if all the appointments listed are for `"Frank"`. So I have to write coding in `cypress` to check if all the first column cell values are `"Frank"`.

---

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add the html and the code you tried to the question.

Answer (score 1):

retrieve all the first columns using cy.get() with the proper selector, then use the each command to validate the content of each cell, something like this

```
cy.get("selector for first colums").each(($el, index, $list) => {
   cy.wrap($el).contains('Frank')
})
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It gets the first cell of the selected column only